# Trying to return filename with relative expression

Tags: bash

```
for SAMPLE in {1..6} 
do
#set input file 1 to "FL1", input file 2 to "FL2"
FL1=path/to/file/*_S${SAMPLE}_*_read1_*.fq.gz
FL2=path/to file/*_S${SAMPLE}_*_read2_*.fq.gz
{code continue to another funtion}
```

So I am trying to return two reads of the same sample using bash and I need to get two inputs for the following function of the same sample number.

However, the code only returns with the sample number like `path/to/file/*_S1_*_read1_*.fq.gz` leaving the wildcard `*` in the variable.

I also have tried leading with `^` and `~=` and neither fixed it. I feel like this is simple but I cannot determine where I am messing up.

My goal for sample 1, for example, is to get `F1` to equal `restoffilename_S1_read1_restoffile.fq.gz`

Comment: `FL1=(path/to/file/*_S${SAMPLE}_*_read1_*.fq.gz)`

Comment: Wildcard expressions only get expanded into lists of matching filenames in certain situations, and the right side of an assignment isn't one of them. How are you trying to use the variables/filenames?

Comment: so I have a ton of NGS samples (like 30 with 2 reads each) and I need to run them through a cleaning program where each command for each sample needs two inputs read 1 and read 2 but the input files need to be from the same sample.
before anyone asks bioinformatics forms say this is a bash question due to it not being about any packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote the path to deal with file names containing spaces:

```
FL1="path/to/file/*_S${SAMPLE}_*_read1_*.fq.gz"
```

or use a command substitution (documented in section "Command Substitution" in `man  bash`):

```
FL1=$(echo "path/to/file/*_S${SAMPLE}_*_read1_*.fq.gz")
```

If there are matches the asterisk will not expand.

Comment: I'd use `/bin/ls` instead of bare `ls`.

Comment: Yeah, that helps if `ls` is aliased. Or `command ls`. Answer updated

Comment: In my case ls is a function in .bashrc:
`ls () 
{ 
    LC_COLLATE="C" $LSBIN -la --ignore=lost+found --color=always --block-size="'1" "$@" | $LESSBIN -S
}`. I'll spare you the expansions of LSBIN and LESSBIN. ;-)

Comment: I'd just use `echo` instead of `ls` (or any variant of it). The wildcard expansion will be done before the filename(s) are passed to whatever command it is, and (hopefully) the only thing `ls` doing is looking at each one, saying "yep, that's a file" to itself, and printing it. The "yep, that's a file" step is a waste of time, and if `ls` does much of anything else it's more likely to cause trouble than help. `echo` won't bother with any of that, it just does the part you need: printing the arguments it got.

Comment: After doing more testing I see that `FILE=dir/*.gz` and `FILE=$(echo dir/*.gz)` give the same output. When there are no matches the asterisk will not expand.

Comment: Yeah I chose to use the echo and got the output I needed to give to the rest of the script